Azure Language service issue while creating Project
I have created Azure search and language service in Enterprise scale environment means both are restricted from Public Access and connected through Private endpoints.
We have hub-spoke model where private endpoints are created for paas services and DNS records are getting created in central dns.
All traffic is routed to Azure firewall using route table.
Spoke subscription is peered with Hub subscription.
I have owner access role on the subscription.
Still I am not able to create Project in Language service under Custom question answer category.
Please help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

